# How does verilog concatenation work when used as both sides of a non-blocking assignement?

Tags: verilog, hdl, 8051

I am a beginner when it comes to verilog or any HDL. While working on a project I found a post where someone uses concatenation in both sides of the non-blocking assignment.

Like so:

```
{tf0, th0,tl0} <= {1'b0, th0, tl0}+ 1'b1;
```

I don't really understand how this works.

This is part of an implementation of a timer module in a Intel 8051 micro-controller implementation .
This is the whole relevant code part for this problem:

```
module oc8051_tc (clk, rst, 
            data_in,
            wr_addr,
        wr, wr_bit,
        ie0, ie1,
        tr0, tr1,
        t0, t1,
            tf0, tf1,
        pres_ow,
//registers
        tmod, tl0, th0, tl1, th1);

input [7:0]  wr_addr,
             data_in;
input        clk,
             rst,
         wr,
         wr_bit,
         ie0,
         ie1,
         tr0,
         tr1,
         t0,
         t1,
         pres_ow;
output [7:0] tmod,
             tl0,
         th0,
         tl1,
         th1;
output       tf0,
             tf1;


reg [7:0] tmod, tl0, th0, tl1, th1;
reg tf0, tf1_0, tf1_1, t0_buff, t1_buff;

wire tc0_add, tc1_add;

assign tc0_add = (tr0 & (!tmod[3] | !ie0) & ((!tmod[2] & pres_ow) | (tmod[2] & !t0 & t0_buff)));
assign tc1_add = (tr1 & (!tmod[7] | !ie1) & ((!tmod[6] & pres_ow) | (tmod[6] & !t1 & t1_buff)));
assign tf1= tf1_0 | tf1_1;

//
// read or write from one of the addresses in tmod
//
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
 if (rst) begin
   tmod <=#1 `OC8051_RST_TMOD;
 end else if ((wr) & !(wr_bit) & (wr_addr==`OC8051_SFR_TMOD))
    tmod <= #1 data_in;
end

//
// TIMER COUNTER 0
//
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
 if (rst) begin
   tl0 <=#1 `OC8051_RST_TL0;
   th0 <=#1 `OC8051_RST_TH0;
   tf0 <= #1 1'b0;
   tf1_0 <= #1 1'b0;
 end else if ((wr) & !(wr_bit) & (wr_addr==`OC8051_SFR_TL0)) begin
   tl0 <= #1 data_in;
   tf0 <= #1 1'b0;
   tf1_0 <= #1 1'b0;
 end else if ((wr) & !(wr_bit) & (wr_addr==`OC8051_SFR_TH0)) begin
   th0 <= #1 data_in;
   tf0 <= #1 1'b0;
   tf1_0 <= #1 1'b0;
 end else begin
     case (tmod[1:0]) /* synopsys full_case parallel_case */
      `OC8051_MODE0: begin                       // mode 0
        tf1_0 <= #1 1'b0;
        if (tc0_add)
          {tf0, th0,tl0[4:0]} <= #1 {1'b0, th0, tl0[4:0]}+ 1'b1;
      end
      `OC8051_MODE1: begin                       // mode 1
        tf1_0 <= #1 1'b0;
        if (tc0_add)
          {tf0, th0,tl0} <= #1 {1'b0, th0, tl0}+ 1'b1;
      end

      `OC8051_MODE2: begin                       // mode 2
        tf1_0 <= #1 1'b0;
        if (tc0_add) begin
      if (tl0 == 8'b1111_1111) begin
            tf0 <=#1 1'b1;
            tl0 <=#1 th0;
           end
          else begin
            tl0 <=#1 tl0 + 8'h1;
            tf0 <= #1 1'b0;
          end
    end
      end
      `OC8051_MODE3: begin                       // mode 3

     if (tc0_add)
       {tf0, tl0} <= #1 {1'b0, tl0} +1'b1;

         if (tr1 & pres_ow)
       {tf1_0, th0} <= #1 {1'b0, th0} +1'b1;

      end
/*      default:begin
        tf0 <= #1 1'b0;
        tf1_0 <= #1 1'b0;
      end*/
    endcase
 end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

A concatenation on the RHS of the assignment is a *packing* operation. It is going to take its 3 operands and pack them into a 17-bit value. The first operand (`1'b0`) becomes the most significant bit(MSB) and the last operand (`tl0`) becomes the least significant bits(LSBs). That value then gets incremented by one, and the result gets scheduled for assignment to the LHS.

A concatenation on the LHS of the assignment is an *unpacking* operation. The first operand (`tf0`) gets the MSB of the result and the last operand (`tl0`) gets the LSBs.

Note that a packing concatenation may contain read-only literals and constants, but an unpacking concatenation must be all writable variables.